# Java Bank program. How to let customer have multiple accounts?

Tags: java

I'm making a bank program in java and have 5 classes:
Account, SavingsAccount (inherits Account), CreditAccount (inherits Account), Bank, Customer.

The program is working as it is, but I can't figure out how to make a customer have two or more accounts. Lets say that one customer wants both a credit account AND a savings account, or maybe two savings accounts.

Can anyone give me some suggestions? Thank you

Bank class:

```
public class Bank {
    String bankName;
    private Customer[] customers = new Customer[100];

    Bank(String bankName) {
        this.bankName = bankName;
    }

    public Customer[] getCustomer() {
        return customers;
    }  

   public String getBankname() {
       return bankName;
   }
}
```

Account class:

```
public abstract class Account {
    protected double balance = 0;
    protected String accountId;

   public Account() {}  //Defaultkonstruktor

   public Account(double bal, String id) {   //Konstruktor
       if (balance >= 0) {
           balance = bal;
       }
       else {
           balance = 0;
       }
       accountId = id;
   }

   public abstract void deposit(double amount); 

   public abstract void withdraw(double amount);

   public abstract double getBalance();

   public abstract String getAccountId();

   public abstract void transfer(double amount, Account account);
}
```

SavingsAccount class: (CreditAccount class is similar)

```
public class SavingsAccount extends Account{ 
    private double interest = 2.9;

    public SavingsAccount() {      //Konstruktor
        super();
    }

    public SavingsAccount(double balance, String id) {   //Konstruktor
        super(bal,id);
    }

    public void setInterest(Customer customer) {
      //code
    }

    public void setBalance(double balance) {
       //code
    }

    @Override
    public void deposit(double amount) {
       //code
    }

    @Override
    public void withdraw(double amount) {
       //code
    }

    @Override
    public double getBalance(){
       //code
    }

    @Override
    public String getAccountId(){
       //code
    }

    @Override
    public void transfer(double amount, Account account) {
       //code
    }

    public void setInterest(double interest){
       //code
    }

    public double getInterest(){
      //code
    }
}
```

Customer class:

```
public class Customer {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String number;

    private SavingsAccount account = new SavingsAccount();
    private CreditAccount cAccount = new CreditAccount();

    Customer(String firstName, String lastName, String number, SavingsAccount account) {   
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.number = number;
        this.account = account;
     }

    Customer(String firstName, String lastName, String number, CreditAccount cAccount) {   
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.number = number;
        this.cAccount = cAccount;
    }

    public SavingsAccount getAccount() {
        return account;
    }

    public CreditAccount getCreditAccount() {
        return cAccount;
    }            
}
```

Main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int choice;
    int numberOfCustomers = 0;
    boolean endProgram = false;
    String bankName;   
    System.out.print("Name of bank: ");
    bankName = input.next();
    Bank bank = new Bank(bankName);
    String accountId;

    SavingsAccount acc = new SavingsAccount();  
    Customer[] customer = bank.getCustomer();            

    do {        
        System.out.println("    " + bank.getBankname() + "\n");
        System.out.println("    1. See balance                          ");
        System.out.println("    2. Withdraw                             ");
        System.out.println("    3. Deposit                              ");
        System.out.println("    4. Transfer                             ");
        System.out.println("    5. Add interest                         ");
        System.out.println("    6. Add new customer                     ");
        System.out.println("    7. Show customers                       ");
        System.out.println("    8. Change interest                      ");
        System.out.println("    0. Exit                                 ");            

        choice = input.nextInt();

        switch(choice) {

            case 1:  
                //code                        
                break;


            case 2: 
                //code
                break;


            case 3: 
                //code
                break;


            case 4: 
                //code
                break;                   


            case 5: 
                //code
                break;


            case 6: //Add customer                   
                System.out.println("Choose account: ");
                System.out.println("1. Savings account");
                System.out.println("2. Credit account");
                choice = input.nextInt();
                switch(choice) {

                    case 1:     //Create savings account
                        System.out.print("Enter amount to deposit: ");
                        double amount = input.nextDouble();
                        System.out.println("Account number is: " + numberOfCustomers);
                        SavingsAccount savingsAccount = new SavingsAccount(amount, String.valueOf(numberOfCustomers));                    
                        System.out.print("First name: ");
                        String firstName = input.next();
                        System.out.print("Last name: ");
                        String lastName = input.next();
                        System.out.print("Customer number: ");
                        String pnumber = input.next();

                        Customer newCustomer = new Customer(firstName, lastName, pnumber, savingsAccount);
                        customer[numberOfCustomers] = newCustomer;
                        numberOfCustomers++;              

                        break;

                    case 2:     //Create credit account
                        System.out.print("Enter amount to deposit: ");
                        double amount = input.nextDouble();
                        System.out.println("Account number is: " + numberOfCustomers);
                        CreditAccount creditAccount = new CreditAccount(amount, String.valueOf(numberOfCustomers));                    
                        System.out.print("First name: ");
                        String firstName = input.next();
                        System.out.print("Last name: ");
                        String lastName = input.next();
                        System.out.print("Customer number: ");
                        String pnumber = input.next();

                        Customer newCustomer = new Customer(firstName, lastName, pnumber, creditAccount);
                        customer[numberOfCustomers] = newCustomer;
                        numberOfCustomers++;                    

                        break;                            
                }
                break;


            case 7: 
                //code
                break;


            case 8: 
                //code                    
                break;  


            case 0: 
                //code
                break;
        }
    } while (!endProgram);
}
```

Comment: In the Customer class, use a `List<Account>` instead of individual fields.

Comment: Give Customer a collection of Accounts such as an `ArrayList<Account>` with which it can hold multiple Account objects. Note, @DaveMorrissey gives the better response, to make the accountList variable of type `List<Account>` since it is almost always best to "code to the interface" rather than the concrete class, but that's the subject of another discussion.

Answer (score 6):

First off rename Account to AbstractAccount and create an Account interface, your Credit and Saving accounts are concrete implementations. Then in your Customer class declare a variable accounts which is a List accounts. Something like

```
public class Customer {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String number;

    private List<Account> accounts;
```

Your Account interface might look like

```
interface Account {

    public void deposit(double amount); 

    public void withdraw(double amount);

    public double getBalance();

    public String getAccountId();
}
```

Your existing class gets refactored

```
 public abstract AbstractAccount implements Account {
     ....
 }
```

Your SavingAccount becomes

```
 public SavingAccount extends AbstractAccount {
  ....
 }
```

I'd be a little worried that this method is declared as abstract on the Account class. Why would a transfer be implemented differently on two different classes?

```
 public abstract void transfer(double amount, Account account);
```

I suggest this method would be belong more to an AccountManager class which would ensure the correct amount is credited/debited from two accounts.

```
 public void transfer(double amount, Account fromAccount, Account toAccount);
```

This class could then check that the 'fromAccount' has the required funds available to transfer as a validation step before the actual transfer happens.

Comment: 1+, plus methods such as `addAccount(Account account)`, `removeAccount(Account account)`, `Account getAccount(String accountId)`,...

Comment: Do you mean 
private List<Account> accounts;
INSTEAD of 
private SavingsAccount account = new SavingsAccount();
private CreditAccount cAccount = new CreditAccount(); ???4

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Do you mean those methods in the Customer class?

Comment: @user2939293: yes, of course. If you had the `List<Accounts>`, then Customer would not have the SavingsAccount or CheckingAccount variables, and you would need some way of giving each Customer the Accounts that he needs.

Comment: @emeraldjava I'm not sure what you want me to do with my Account class? It's abstract now since I have abstract methods. How do I make it an interface instead?

Comment: See the proposed Account interfac. Using an interface is considered best practice. Consider in the future if you needed to add a new account type, say an OverdraftAccount. Using an Account interface would mean your Customer class could just start using the new account type without any change.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of get to Customer's object constructor SavingsAccount or CreditAccount,
you may use:

```
Customer(String firstName, String lastName, String number) {    
...
}
```

And add set method to account and cAccount:

```
Public void setAccount(SavingAccount account) {
    This.account = account;
}
```

of course you could create a list like in the previous comment:

and add method:

```
public void addAccount(Account account) {
    accounts.add(account);
}
```

Comment: Ok, I now have changed Customer class to this:
public class Customer {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String number;
      
    private ArrayList<Account> accounts;
        
    Customer(String firstName, String lastName, String number, Account account) { 
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.number = number;
        this.accounts = account;
    }
    
    public ArrayList<Account> getAccount() {
        return accounts;
    }
}

Comment: I get an error message on this.accounts = account; It says Account can not be converted to ArrayList<Account>. What can I do to deal with the problem? Thank you guys!